# biblatex: change of sorting not working unless I delete .bbl file

Tags: biblatex, texstudio

I can't change the sorting of the bibliography unless I delete the according .bbl file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
sorting=nyt
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}
Anyway

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

If I change the sorting, the bibliography doesn't show up.

The sample.bib file:

```
@article{einstein,
    author = "Albert Einstein",
    title = "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal = "Annalen der Physik",
    volume = "322",
    number = "10",
    pages = "891--921",
    year = "1905",
    DOI = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
    keywords = "physics"
}

@book{dirac,
    title = {The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
    author = {Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
    isbn = {9780198520115},
    series = {International series of monographs on physics},
    year = {1981},
    publisher = {Clarendon Press},
    keywords = {physics}
}

@online{knuthwebsite,
    author = "Donald Knuth",
    title = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url  = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html",
    addendum = "(accessed: 01.09.2016)",
    keywords = "latex,knuth"
}

@inbook{knuth-fa,
    author = "Donald E. Knuth",
    title = "Fundamental Algorithms",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    year = "1973",
    chapter = "1.2",
    keywords  = "knuth,programming"
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running Biber manually on your file or are you using some kind of helper tool to do that? If you change the sorting option you need to run at least LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX. If you are using a helper tool that runs Biber only if the `.bbl` is missing or some other criteria are satisfied (changed `.bib`? changed `.aux`?), then you may have to manually remove the `.bbl` for it to rerun Biber. Advanced tools like `latexmk` usually get this right.

Comment: I'm using TeXStudio with the default options running biber.

Comment: I see, I'm not a big TeXstudio user (I use it at work occasionally) and I have never really figured out how it decides when to run Biber. I guess you could visit the TeXstuio forum at https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/, open a feature request at the TeXstudio bugtracker (https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues) or hope that someone who knows drops by here. But I doubt that you change the sorting that often so I assume you can live with this minor inconvenience.

Comment: That's true, but thanks very much anyway.